# Confusion about right folds in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lambda, fold

Just for Background **I am a Haskell and FP Beginner, self-learning.**

I was going through folds on [Learn You a Haskell for great good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#folds).

In this I came across this function

```
map' :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]  
map' f xs = foldr (\x acc -> f x : acc) [] xs
```

Everything is good but as far as I understood the first parameter of the lambda `x` matches with `[]` and second `acc` matches with `xs`. Right? The confusion starts with the author saying that `Then, we prepend it to the accumulator, which is was [].` How is the second parameter `acc` matching with `[]` which is the first argument? Doesn't make sense.

But his implementation is working while mine (with [] and xs interchanged as parameters) is giving a big error

```
Practice.hs:88:41:
    Couldn't match type `a' with `b'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for map' :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
          at Practice.hs:87:9
      `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for map' :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
          at Practice.hs:87:9
    Expected type: [b]
      Actual type: [a]
    In the second argument of `foldr', namely `xs'
    In the expression: foldr (\ x acc -> f x : acc) xs []
    In an equation for map':
        map' f xs = foldr (\ x acc -> f x : acc) xs []
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

What am I missing here? Does `foldr` use `flip` internally? Or did I just understood it all incorrectly?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what you mean by "matches with". Eventually, in your example, the given function gets called with `[]` in it's *second* argument.

Comment: The lambda is not applied to `[]` and `xs`.  Instead it's the first argument to `foldr`.  The second and third arguments to `foldr` are `[]` and `xs` respectively.

Comment: @DavidYoung What I meant was that it looked to me that the first parameter(to lambda) corresponded to first argument(The `[]`) like in imperative programming. I had forgotten that the lambda was also an argument to `foldr` alongwith the other 2 arguments. And it was upto `foldr` to apply it to its 2 other arguments. Just like @TomEllis said.

Comment: @TomEllis You should make that comment into an answer. That was the main thing that I had overlooked which led to this question.

Comment: OK, I made it an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lambda is not applied to `[]` and `xs`. Instead it's the first argument to `foldr`. The second and third arguments to foldr are `[]` and `xs` respectively.

Answer (score 3):

It helps to look at what the "symbolic" form of the fold functions looks like. If we have a list of arbitrary elements `[b1, b2, b3, b4]` and initial element `a` then:

```
foldr f a [b1, b2, b3, b4] = f b1 (f b2 (f b3 (f b4 a)))
```

Conversely the foldl would look like.

```
foldl f a [b1, b2, b3, b4] = f (f (f (f a b1) b2) b3) b4
```

This of course ignores the laziness component of the execution, but the general idea still holds.

In your function you fold a function of two arguments which pushes a an element transformed under `f` onto a cons list.

```
map' f xs = foldr (\x acc -> f x : acc) [] xs
```

Expanding this out where (`xs=[x0,x1,...,xn]`) like above yields:

```
map' f xs = (f x0 : (f x1 : (f x2 : ... (f xn : []))))
```

Where the ellipsis is just pseudocode for the all the elements in between. We see is just precisely the element wise map. Hope that helps build intuition.

Comment: `foldr g z [a,b,c,...,n] == g a (g b (g c (... (g n z)...)))` seems more visually apparent for me, but YMMV. :)

Comment: This expansion really helped me understand what is going on. But the following sentence looked like a tongue twister to me. `In your function you fold a function of two arguments which pushes a an element transformed under f onto a cons list.` Just to be clear about this, here`your function` is `map'` and `a function` is the lambda. Correct?

Comment: @AseemBansal (since Stephen is off-line, I'll answer) yes. The lambda expression defines a function of two arguments. BTW I prefer `r` ("recursive result") instead of `acc` ("accumulator"), which is more suitable for left folds. mnemonics. :)

Answer (score 2):

Begin with the type of `foldr`, from [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=foldr).

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

From this, it is apparent that the *second* argument of the lambda must match the second argument to `foldr`, i.e. `acc` matches `[]` and `x` is an element of `xs`, because the first argument of the lambda has type `a`, and the third argument of `foldr` has type `[a]`.

Note that `foldl` and `foldr` have different signatures, and hence the arguments in the lambda are swapped.

Comment: This helped me understand the usefulness of type signature and proved that what was happening was right. But it didn't solve the overall confusion. Still thanks. It helped.

Answer (score 2):

Might be simplest to just look at the implementation of `foldr`:

```
foldr            :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr k z = go
          where
            go []     = z
            go (y:ys) = y `k` go ys
```

Then take a simple example like:

```
foldr (+) 0 [0, 1, 2, 4]
```

And follow exactly what happens as it recurses and generates the "spine".

Image of a `foldr` spine:

[image]

I'd recommend tracing what happens using pen and paper.

Comment: Nice graphic, did you make that or find it somewhere?

Comment: I was hoping you had a nifty program to do that for you!

Comment: @Eric well, there is: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4-212uMgy8 (Vacuum), but the OP should learn this by using pen and paper.

Comment: Pretty, but this answer omits any reference whatsoever to the context in which the OP is stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another explanation, using long variable names for effect:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f = foldr step []
    where 
      -- If you have an incomplete solution to your problem, and the first
      -- element of the input list, what is the last step you need to finish? 
      step elem incompleteSolution = f elem : incompleteSolution
```

The neat thing about using functions like `foldr` is that when you write your `step` function, the second argument to `step` will be the correct result for a smaller version of your problem.

One useful way to think of it is to imagine that `foldr` has already solved *nearly* all of your problem, but it's still missing the last step.  For example, if you're trying to solve `map f (x:xs)`, picture that `foldr` has already computed the solution for `map f xs`.  Using that incomplete solution, `f` and `x`, what is the final step you need to perform to arrive at the complete solution?  Well, as the code snippet illustrates, you apply `f` to `x`, and put that in front of the incomplete solution, and you're done.

The magic of `foldr` is that once you've figured out what to write for `step`, and what to use for the `[]` base case, then you're done.  Your `step` function doesn't concern itself with the input list—all it can see is one input list element and an incomplete solution.